# Using java libraries on iphone apps

Tags: java, iphone, ios, dll, jar

I have to develop an iPhone app and I have to use some java libraries, is there a way to do it?, or what options do I have?, I thought maybe to use this libraries with server calls (using web services maybe) but i don't know if it is possible either. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to use Java libraries directly on the iPhone. You need to find some Objective-C equivalent.

Your idea to use server-side code and call it from the iPhone sounds more reasonable, however, you need to consider the drawbacks of this solution:

- Network bandwith and latency
- iPhone must be online for the libraries to work